# How to purge messages for specific users in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, purge

Hey so I was trying to make a command in discord.py rewrite version was doing something like `>purgemessage 5` would purge 5 messages of the user who sent that message but for some reason, it won't work. I am using this in a reply so it won't show the error;-; but here is what I have done so far to try to make it work!

```
# purges author's messages
@commands.command(name='purgemessage', aliases=['pm'])
@commands.cooldown(1, 300)
@commands.has_any_role(OwnerRole, GuildMasterRole, AdminRole, ExclusiveMemberRole)
async def purgemessage(self, ctx, amount:int, *, arg:str=None):
    msg = []
    channel = ctx.message.channel.history(limit=None)
    async for message in channel:
        if message.author == ctx.message.author:
            msg.append(message)
    await ctx.message.channel.delete_messages(msg)
    await asyncio.sleep(.5)
    botMessage = await ctx.send(f'**{amount}** messages were successfully deleted!')
    await asyncio.sleep(.5)
    await botMessage.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done thorough tests, but the first error I am getting (after rewriting to work outside a cog so I could quickly test), is

> discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50034): You can only bulk delete messages that are under 14 days old.

This error might be caused by your code not containing anything to stop adding messages after reaching `amount`, and continuing backward for a user's entire history in a channel.
This could very well not be the error you're getting, depending on the channel you're testing in. I would highly recommend you start working on an environment that will show you errors so we can help you better.
I don't know enough to debug the code you've given, but here's something that does what you want in less code and I know works:

```py
channel = ctx.channel
await channel.purge(limit=amount, check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
```

`ctx.channel` is the channel the command was sent in, `ctx.author` is who sent it.
`channel.purge` will [purge](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=purge#discord.TextChannel.purge) `limit` amount of messages that meet the `check` function, which in this case is a lambda (a function defined in one line, looks like this: `lambda argument: expression`. The lambda will implictly return the expression).

The check keyword will pass `message` as an argument, so I've named by lambda argument appropriately. The expression checks that the message we're checking (`message.author`) was written by the invoker of the command (`ctx.author`).

This code works, even for messages over 14 days old, but it does take some time for larger amounts of messages.

Comment: Hey so I saw what you wrote I also did some research since I didn't know some of the stuff in there such as lambda so now I know what that is, but now when I run the command `>purgemessage 5` it works for the first time then it stops working unless I reload the file, I tried using a different bot so I could check the error on Visual Code Studio but there is no error in the output so I am in a bit of a pickle right now. I tried creating the check outside of the purge function then putting it in there but that also didn't work.

Comment: When you say it stops working do you mean the bot ends or the purge command doesn't purge?

Comment: Are you really sure the problem is the purge command? I'm not able to recreate your issue.

Comment: Using the purge command works on the first try but won't work on the 2nd or 3rd or 4rth tries and so on. If it works for you then I probably messed something up so will take a look at it again.